# MAC problem. not a valid identifier when export variable

Tags: macos, bash, export, environment-variables

when i try to export a variable, some problem occur.

this is what i want:

`export env.SOMETHING=/Users/Me/repo/main/ver`

this is what i get:

`-bash: export: 'env.SOMETHING=/Users/Me/repo/main/ver': not a valid identifier`

Comment: Hi Dani, let us know what you needed to create the `SOMETHING` variable for, ie. what language or application, so that searches bring other people here for the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

As of version 3 of Bash, periods are not allowed within variable names.

You could use `_` instead e.g.

```
export env_SOMETHING=/Users/Me/repo/main/ver
```

Comment: but I need to export env.SOMETHING is it impossible to do that?

Comment: @Dani You probably need to export SOMETHING instead of env.SOMETHING and just misread the documentation or whatever tells you to export the variable.